# Useful jyggen/Response error message?

Tags: php, symfony, curl

The response from a jyggen/Curl request is based on the Symfony 2 `Response`, documented [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html).

In my code, after a `Request` is executed, both the `Request.isSuccessful()` and `Response.isSuccessful()` conditions must pass for the script to continue.

If the `Request` fails I can use `$request->getErrorMessage()` to log a suitable exception.

If the `Request` succeeds but the `Response` then fails however, I need something useful to log for it.

I have tried `$response->getContent()` and `$request->getErrorMessage()`, both of which return nothing.

I have currently settled for using `$response->getStatusCode()` for now but I would rather have more information. Doing a `var_dump` of the response shows there is both a status code and status code text stored as protected values, the text providing a message along with the code although this can be worked out from the code value anyway.

Is there a call I have missed or a better way to find the reason for the `Response`'s failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$request->getErrorMessage()` for total failures and `$response->getStatusCode()` with invalid response seems to cover enough bases for now. I could use a way to return the failed URL along with the response status code for when the `Request` succeeds with an invalid `Response` but I should be able to find that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what response data you want to access, can you give me some more information?

You can always use `$request->getRawResponse()` to retrieve the raw HTTP output. That method combined with `$request->getInfo()` (see `curl_getinfo`) should give you everything that is available about the response.

However, you really shouldn't have to parse the HTTP output manually. If I've missed to enable public access to some vital response information, please create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/jyggen/curl/issues?sort=updated&state=open).

Comment: I was basically looking for the equivalent of `$request->getErrorMessage()` for `Response`, I will test getInfo when I get the chance and see what I get.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not sure what ``$response->getErrorMessage()`` would return. If the request is successful there's always a response (whether it's 200, 404, 500 etc.).

Comment: True but since we can identify if the response is successful it would be useful to have a status message to go with it.